# Attic Insulation Retrofit with XPS Foam Board

Tags: insulation, remodeling, vapor-barrier, retrofit

I have an attic space in my house that has been converted into part of the interior envelope and is now heated. Unfortunately, the rafters making up the ceiling are only 2x6 and contain only R-21 batts (slightly compressed by the air baffles to maintain air flow at the exterior roof sheathing). This of course is entirely inadequate. The space was too cool in winter and condensation would form in various places where there was dead airspace, or on the skylight. I then provided some heat to this space to move the dew point and get rid of the condensation. I also ran a dehumidifier in the space to pull some of the moisture out of the air.

The problem is that when I added heat to this space, snow that would normally remain on the roof is now melting and forming ice dams at the eves of the house. My proposed solution is to take down the vapor barrier and add 3 inches of XPS foam and seal it with tape and where needed, spray foam. I would also use an HRV to pull air from the space and discontinue the dehumidifier.

Here is the question: According to my calculations, the dewpoint in the new roof assembly would be somewhere in the thickness of the 3" foam board. Is this actually a problem? Where is the vapor retarder actually located relative to the total assembly. I am allowed by code in my area to have 42% of my R-value on the "warm in winter side" of the vapor retarder to avoid condensation. So, is the vapor retarder on the inside surface of the XPS, the outside surface, or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: You really might want to take some of that stuff out to the fire pit and do a flame test.  I'd use it all day if fires did not exist, but they do, and the stuff is like gasoline, especially the canned spray foam.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the combustable properties of foam. Code allows it, but it must be protected by drywall. Sorry I didn't mention that above.